# Запрос имени из базы данных

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Создаю настольное приложение на C# с помощью Windows Forms в Visual Studio. Имеется база данных следующей структуры:
[image: База данных]

Имеется следующая форма:
[image: Форма]

При нажатии на кнопку "Войти" срабатывает следующий код:

```
    {
        string loginUser = textBox1.Text;
        string passwordUser = textBox2.Text;
        string nameUser;
        DB db = new DB();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @lU AND `password` = @pU", db.getConnection());
        command.Parameters.Add("@lU", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
        command.Parameters.Add("@pU", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordUser;
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            User a = new User();
            a.login = loginUser;
            a.password = passwordUser;
            MessageBox.Show("Вход успешен");
            this.Hide();
            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(a);
            mainForm.Show();
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
    }
```

Код проверяет поля Login и Password и даёт нам пользователя из БД, после чего переходит к следующей форме.
[image: Логин форма]

Задача состоит в том, что программа должна взять из БД имя (и фамилию) пользователя, который вошёл в свою учётную запись и подставить вместо "Имя". Как это сделать?

Comment: вы по логину и паролю уже нашли юзера, вот и сохраните его куда нибудь и показывайте его имя везде, где вам нужно.

Comment: Да, но я не знаю как взять имя пользователя, в этом и заключается вопрос.

Comment: возьмите из таблицы, что вы заполнили адаптером

Comment: `table.Rows[0]["Name"]`